# create and compare child classes

Tags: java, inheritance, parent-child

Hi guys sorry if this is a common and annoying question, im trying to make a parent class (for 3 individual classes), but im really not sure on where to go from here.

I need them to all spawn randomly within the limits of 0<=x<=100 and 0<=y<=100 and cant be anymore than 1 decimal point. (i will need to be able to compare the 'child' classes' distance from each other later on).

Or do i not need 3 new classes but instead i can do it all in the same class?

also please feel free to add suggestions if you think i need it.

TIA

```
public class Soldier {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

            Random random = new Random();
            double max = 100; //sets the limit to 100 for the soldiers spawn
            double min = 0; //sets the minimum to 0 for the soldiers spawn
            double xPos = Math.random() * (max - min) - min;//for the x coordinate of the soldiers position
            double yPos = Math.random() * (max - min) - min; //for the y coordinate of the soldiers position
            xPos = Math.round(xPos * 10) / 10.0d; //making sure the x value is to 1dp
            yPos = Math.round(yPos * 10) / 10.0d; //making sure the y value is to 1dp
            System.out.println("(" + xPos + " ," + yPos + ")"); //printing out the position of the soldier (x, y)

        }

    }
```

Comment: Your question seems to consist of at least 3 questions with 0 of them expressed clearly enough to give you a proper answer. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? What lead you to thinking about child classes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if parent-child has anything to do with it, but here is what I think you want:

```
public static void main(String ... args){
  double min = 0;
  double max = 100;

  Point p1 = generatePoint(min, max);
  Point p2 = generatePoint(min, max);
  Point p3 = generatePoint(min, max);
}

public static Point generatePoint(double min, double max){
  double xPos = Math.random() * (max - min) - min;
  double yPos = Math.random() * (max - min) - min; 

  return new Point((int) xPos, (int) yPos);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, one last thing, how can i make this double instead of int? 

return new Point((int) xPos, (int) yPos);

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need 3 classes, just 3 instances of objects of this class. I would add an "id" member to the class so you can differentiate between them. I would also add a couple of class-wide *static* members, one to track what "id" we are on as we instance more soldiers, and maybe an array of pointers to those instances, to make it easier to find and operate on the instances.